# how to aggregate daily activities of users into weekly

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, aggregate-functions

I have the following tables,first one (vle) has behavioral activities ( many types of activities, some shown in the activity type column), and the other (UsersVle) has users' activities.The date column represents a day and starts from 0 till 222. I want to aggregate users' activities into weeks based on the activity types. For example in a week1 user1 will have columns as the number of activities types, and each column includes the total sum_clicks during that week. I wonder how I can do that in a pandas data frame using python?
I will appreciate your help.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Derive a new field called `WEEK` from `date` (you haven't provided enough info about `date` to suggest how to translate it to a week (e.g. 1 = Jan 1st?))
2. Join your two tables.  Is `id_site` in table 2 a foreign key for `id_site` in table 1?  If so, `combined_df = table2.merge(table1, on='id_site')`.  Now, you should have all the fields in a single data frame.
3. Pivot like this: `user_summary_by_week = pd.pivot_table(combined_df, index=['id_user', 'WEEK'], columns='activity_type', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0).reset_index(col_level=1)`

Comment: I wanted to make a file or a data frame that includes each user's weekly sum_clicks activities. the number of columns (activity-types like r, o, url, s, etc) will be the same for each user in the module. Could you please update your answer to work on weeks?

Comment: It looks like you just mentioned the logic to create the WEEK field, so why not create it and apply the algorithm? What more do you need from me?

Comment: First, Thank you, Jesse. floor(date+1/7) – 1 is not working correctly. The date information is in days thus 0-6 means week 0, 7-13 means week 1. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: I solved the issue related to week logic. I have a question: as you can see the order (id_site, model, presentation) in table1 should be the same as in table 2, but the order in table 2 is model, presentation, and id_site. using this combined_df = table2.merge(table1, on='id_site') will result into module_x,presentation_x and module_y, presentation_y. I tried this way cdf = table2.merge(table1,how='left',left_on=['id_site','module','presentation'],right_on=['id_site','module','presentation']). I wonder if it right?

Comment: Yes, that should work, the small difference I would recommend is using inner join (remove "how='left' as the default is 'inner').  This is because for each record you need values for 'activity_type' and 'sum_click.'  Bringing these two fields into 1 table is the point of the merge.  A left join might result in some records having null values in a situation where a record on the right side of the join is missing.

Comment: Thank you so much. I applied 'user_summary_by_week = pd.pivot_table(combined_df, index=['WEEK','id_user'],,columns='activity_type', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0) to be easy for retrieving data by week as separate data frame like 0,1,etc. In the end,I need to do this ,if for example I want w2 dataset , It should be w0+w1+w2, and for w3 , it should be like w0+w1+w2+w3, wn=w0+w1+...+wn-1+wn. I wonder if doing pivote first is right? or there is a way to do that? . The problem of having dataframes as many as weeks is not haveing same id_user due to a user activity.

Comment: I mean So users do not have activities in some weeks so data frames do not have identical id_users